# Lua crashes when compiling test program

Tags: lua, zerobrane

I'm looking to dip my toes into coding with Lua - I'm trying to find something to teach my 11-year-old son some programming skills (he's already mastered Scratch :) ). I'm completely new to Lua myself, but I have some background in other languages.

I've downloaded and installed ZeroBrane (v0.80 running on OS X 10.9.5); however, when I try to compile/run <strike>any of the sample files</strike> the test program `turtle.lua`, I get a crash:

[image]

The same happens if I choose Lua 5.2 as the interpreter. Any ideas as to the possible cause and fix?

EDIT: I was a bit hasty when testing this before; simple Lua code appears to run fine, as do the sample programs in the `turtle-samples` folder.

The sample code `spirograph.lua` runs without crashing, but doesn't appear to actually do anything. `Turtle.lua` still crashes: by stepping through the code, it appears to crash when exiting the loop between lines 543 and 555:

[image]

If I press <kbd>F10</kbd> at this breakpoint, I get the Lua crash.

Comment: Does it happen on all scripts, even a simple one-liner with `print 'Hello World'`? Does it happen when you try to Run or Debug?

Comment: I tested v0.80 on OX 10.9.5, but don't see any issues and there hasn't been other similar reports. You may want to open a [ticket on github](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues).

Comment: @PaulKulchenko: apologies, I should have tested more thoroughly. See my edits above, it's only some sample code that crashes (or, in the case of `spirograph.lua`, doesn't appear to do anything).

Comment: Added an answer; also the title is a bit misleading as it's the lua application that crashes and not the IDE itself.

Comment: Agreed, I've updated the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `turtle.lua` and `spirograph.lua` files are modules, so you don't need to "run" them as they don't do anything by themselves. You can run all the included examples, and those that use those modules run without issues.

Thank you for debugging it; I'll check what may be causing a crash on `turtle.lua`, but you can continue using it as a module without issues.

Comment: Thanks - I'm afraid I'm completely new to Lua so didn't appreciate the distinction between modules and the examples.

Comment: That's not your fault as it shouldn't crash even when loaded as an example; I'll see if this can be fixed. Thank you for the report.

Comment: @KenD, I added a message when you try to load these modules as examples; this eliminates the crash as well. The changes will be included in the next version and are available from [github](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneEduPack).